# How to get json data jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have structured data (json) in my WP blog page. I need to show for users some data from that json.

Json looks like:

```
<script data-snippet_id="" type="application/ld+json"> {
"sku":"",
"mpn":"",
"image":"",
"name":"",
"description":"",
"review": {
    "publisher": {
        "url": "", "name": "", "@context": "", "@type": ""
    }
    ,
    "dateModified":"2020-04-08T19:08:17+03:00",
    "author":[ {
        "name": "", "@context": "http:\/\/schema.org", "@type": "Person"
    }
    ],
    "description":"",
    "dateCreated":"",
    "reviewRating": {
        "ratingValue": "4", "@context": "http:\/\/schema.org", "@type": "Rating"
    }
    ,
    "@context":"http:\/\/schema.org",
    "@type":"Review"
}
,
"@context":"http:\/\/schema.org",
"@type":"Product"}</script>
```

I need to get ratingValue via jquery, to show that for users

i try use function getJSON, but its not working for me

```
$(document).ready(function() { 


            $.getJSON('post', function(emp) { 
                $('#display').html('<p> ratingValue : ' + emp.ratingValue + '</p>'); 

            }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the JSON is being output to the page by PHP into a `<script>` tag then you don't need to use AJAX to retrieve it. You can simply retrieve the `text()` of that element and `JSON.parse()` it.

Also note that the `ratingValue` is nested within the `review.reviewRating` object, so the method of getting the value needs to change slightly. Try this:

```js
let json = JSON.parse($('script[data-snippet_id]').text());
$('#display').html('<p>ratingValue: ' + json.review.reviewRating.ratingValue + '</p>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script data-snippet_id="snip-5e99a87c31435" type="application/ld+json">{"sku":"","mpn":"","image":"","name":"","description":"","review":{"publisher":{"url":"","name":"","@context":"","@type":""},"dateModified":"2020-04-08T19:08:17+03:00","author":[{"name":"","@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"Person"}],"description":"","dateCreated":"","reviewRating":{"ratingValue":"4","@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"Rating"},"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"Review"},"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"Product"}</script>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you!
One more question: how i can add class with ratingValue to the div for take <div id="display" class="4" ?